# EF Core database first replace ForeignKey with entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-6.0

I have database so I use [EF Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools) to generate entities and this is what I got

```
 public partial class ItemNavision
{
    public ItemNavision()
    {
        ExpressionOfNeeds = new HashSet<ExpressionOfNeed>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExpressionOfNeed> ExpressionOfNeeds { get; set; }
}

public partial class ExpressionOfNeed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int IdItemNavision { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemNavision IdItemNavisionNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

I want to change **ExpressionOfNeed** entity to be like this

```
 public partial class ExpressionOfNeed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public ItemNavision ItemNavision { get; set; }
}
```

is there a way to use Fluent API to do this and when saving data to the database the **IdItemNavision** saved automatically

Update
Configurations

```
 public partial class ItemNavisionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ItemNavision>
{
      public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ItemNavision> entity)
      {
        entity.ToTable("ItemNavision");

        entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(500);

        OnConfigurePartial(entity);
    }

    partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<ItemNavision> entity);
}

public partial class ExpressionOfNeedConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ExpressionOfNeed>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExpressionOfNeed> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(d => d.IdItemNavisionNavigation)
            .WithMany(p => p.ExpressionOfNeeds)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdItemNavision)
            .HasConstraintName("FK__Expressio__IdIte__04D07943");

        OnConfigurePartial(entity);
    }

    partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<ExpressionOfNeed> entity);
}
```

Comment: could you share your DBContext? or your Configuration classes if you're using that feature.

Comment: I have Update my question

Comment: You need to add a Shadow Property and configure it as the Foreign Key.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545438/composite-primary-key-as-shadow-property-in-many-to-many-relation

Comment: I'll try it and let you know